# moving a few rows from one table to another and rest to some other

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-ase

I have some staging table to bcp some data from a file to db.
Now from this table i want to copy some 'valid' data to another table, while all other (some invalid, some duplicate) data to another 'error' table.
Can I have someway to do this using some query/stored procedure in Sybase-ASE.
(it would be great if i can use the same thing in oracle as well)

Comment: How to know what data is valid and which invalid?

Comment: i can know the invalid data by checking some particular value in some column. e.g. if value of isValid column is 1 or 0

Comment: A stored procedure is an extremely simple way of accomplishing this, yes.  Just write both inserts, and put them both in your stored procedure with some error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a product exactly for that called "SQL Server Integration Services", or SSIS. This product falls into the ETL category : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load

You can start here to learn more : http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/enterprise-information-management/integration-services.aspx

The product comes with any license of SQL Server.

Comment: I am using sybase ASE in a very restrictive environment, so can't use SSIS